# Difference boolean giving odd results - any help?

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I've got a weird problems when using the boolean tool.

I'm trying to boolean part A and B together using with difference operation (pic 1).   However every time I try to do this by selecting part B and then choosing part A to difference boolean, it only joins the left side of part A to B even though the two pieces of part A were joined in the first place (pic 2).

Then when I click the apply mod, the pieces have joined separately (pic 3) andnot all as one.  I tried then to boolean a new mesh together in the same fashion as before but the parts do the same thing weirdly (pic 4)...

There arent any doubles or duplicate meshes so not sure whats happened.  Anyone offer any help?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Possibly it’s an issue with the meshes being non-manifold, which can cause unexpected results with Boolean operations.

Comment: Remove half of both objects, boolean them and then add Mirror modifier, will be much faster. Depending on the desired result Boolean might not be needed (but anyway it should work generally)

Comment: Thanks Mr Zak, probably shouldve done that in the first place lol